# Laravel Search function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i have a question about the Laravel search function, i had follow the guildeline online and i still fail to search the category, can someone guide me and tell me where i did wrongly ? Much appreciated

**My category Controller php code**:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $posts = DB::table('bit_app_policy_category')->where('id','like','%' .$search. '%')->paginate(5);
    return view('category.index',['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

My index.blade code

```
   <div align="left">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1>Policy</h1>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form action="/search" method="get" role="search">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="_method" placeholder="Search ID / Code"> <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/search','categoryController@search');
```

What error i get is here
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDXsI.png)

[interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGP0o.png)

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsOAS.png)

Comment: What is the `path` for index.php?

Comment: @Digvijay erm Sorry im new to Laravel, what do u mean by path

Comment: What is the column you are trying to search within the table `bit_app_policy_category`? Currently you are searching the `id` column.

Comment: i want to search for ID column, my database table name ( bit_app_policy_category ) , i will upload the picture now

Comment: please put your after resource folder path. of blade file.

Comment: change your index file name if it is `index.php` then `index.blade.php`.

Comment: Your data display only when you filter data with match your database.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `$posts` variable to your view. But the error says you are referencing a `$category` variable.

```
return view('category.index',['posts' => $posts]);
```

Maybe you might want to update view to use `$posts`. If you could post your full code (category/index.blade.php) we might be able to help you better.

__
Here is how I would do:

```
$categories= DB::table('bit_app_policy_category')->where('id','like','%' .$search. '%')->paginate(5);
return view('category.index',['categories' => $categories]); //you can also use compact  return view('category.index', compact('categories') );
```

And to display:

```
@foreach( $categories as $category )
    <div>{{ $category->id }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Another tip: you can name your routes like so

```
Route::get('search','categoryController@search')->name('search');
```

Then you can reference this route (in form or anywhere else you want) like so:

```
<form action="{{ route('search') }}" ..>
```